# Android Notification Push

Tags: android, notifications, server, push

I am new to the Android Development scene and I am currently developing an app in android studio.

What I would like to do is to the send a notification to all the users that installed the app. What tools do I have to use, do I need a server? Also, how do I make the application listen for a push when it is not open and still show the notification?

Answer (score 0):

Follow this link it will work for you

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-templates/tree/master/GcmEndpoints

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Firebase Notifications](https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/). It's very easy to learn and implement from their docs. They also provided sample codes [here](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android).